# Simple image & retina image in one img

Tags: css, safari, retina-display, retina

I have this code:

```
<a href="/smi" class="media-link">
      <img src="/images2/smi.png" alt="About">
</a>
```

**smi.png** - it's simple image

I have **smi2.png** - it's retina image

How can I set two images in this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/smi" class="media-link">
    <img src="/images2/smi.png" srcset="/images2/smi2.png 2x">
</a>
```

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/srcset/w3c-srcset/